# Issue in configuring log in CXF rest service

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf, slf4j

I am trying to configure CXF rest log using `<cxf:bus>` in cxf.xml as below,

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>

    <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/Restful">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="Service" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="Service" class="com.xxx.yyy.services.ServiceImpl" />

    </beans>
```

But while executing my service , it throws below exception,

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'base': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxf' while setting bean property 'bus'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxf.config0' while setting bean property 'busConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf.config0' is defined

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxf.config0' while setting bean property 'busConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf.config0' is defined

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 24 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf.config0' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 34 more
```

Could you please let me know what went wrong here.?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Alternately the below configuration works well,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

<jaxrs:server id="base" address="/Restful">

<jaxrs:serviceBeans>
     <ref bean="Service" />
</jaxrs:serviceBeans>

<jaxrs:features>
     <cxf:logging />
</jaxrs:features>

</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="Service" class="com.xxx.yyy.services.ServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```